# SpriteKit MoveToX:duration from Current Stat

Tags: ios, 2d, sprite-kit, sprite

I am planning to move batch of sprite randomly accross x- axis from left to right say 0 to 320 and 
right to left say 320 to 0 with some **Constant** duration,

Further each sprite i am placing at random position across x-axis,

but when i create my batch of sprite and apply that skaction on each one

```
 SKAction *moveRight  = [SKAction moveToX:320 duration:walkAnim.duration];
 SKAction *moveLeft   = [SKAction moveToX:0 duration:walkAnim.duration];
```

after some time the whole batch of sprites is moving in one direction, from left to right and then right to left

i know the problem is with my approach and to `moveToX` with **Constant** duration

I need **Constant** duration in my case, Is there something we have in `moveToX` like we do have in

```
 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]
```

so that i can tackle the issue for batch sprites with random position across x-axis

**Note** when i give some space to call that action on each sprite, then its working fine, but i need all at one time.

One can get Sample app from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c8lxjcic3s64ei/TexturePacker-SpriteKit-master-2.zip)

**EDIT**

What i need i have updated the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1x9lcboqcmz0pi/TexturePacker-SpriteKit-master-2%202.zip)

but I need all the sprites present on the dice without any Timeinterval with the same actions applied on all of the sprites.

Any suggestion would be appreciated
thanks
Umer

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? If you have constant duration they will of course arrive at the same time, and then start simultaneously to go in the other direction. if you want constant speed you need to calculate the duration for the desired distance.

Comment: i need the movement forever.. with same speed , did you check out the sample app to better understand what i am facing..it is there in the question, i don't want some of sprite to be moved with different speed. i want the same speed for all sprites, that's why i am using constant duration

Comment: I have Updated My Question, so that some one can better understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a constant speed you will need to calculate the duration for the first move Action based on the current position of your sprite. after doing that first move, you can use your `moveRight` and `moveLeft` actions. Here is an example for starting to move Right.

```
CGFloat durationForFullDistance = walkAnim.duration;
CGFloat fullDistance = 320;
CGFloat firstDistance = fullDistance - sprite.position.x; 
CGFloat durationForFirstMove = durationForFullDistance*firstDistance/fullDistance;

SKAction *firstMoveRight  = [SKAction moveToX:320 duration:durationForFirstMove];
SKAction *moveRight  = [SKAction moveToX:320 duration:durationForFullDistance];
SKAction *moveLeft   = [SKAction moveToX:0 duration:durationForFullDistance];

SKAction *continousMove = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                               firstMoveRight,
                                               [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[
                                                                                                  moveLeft,
                                                                                                  moveRight
                                                                                                  ]]]
                                               ]];
]]
```

Comment: so in your case that would mean not to assign self.sequence to the sprites, but create a new sequence with @[firstMove,turn,self.sequence]